# Setting the main window (QWidget) as parent of QML Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QWidget based app, whose main window is a QMainWindow-derived.

A plugin of this app creates a QML engine, and loads QML files, where the toplevel item is always a QML Window type.

The problem is that these QML windows go behind the main window.

Setting `QtQuick.Window`'s `flags` property to contain `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` solves the problem but it is really bad as it forces the QML window to be globally on top of ALL applications.

I guess if the QML Window was child of the main window, then it would never go behind the main window, like it happens for QWidgets.

But how to set the parent of a QML Window to be a QMainWindow/QWidget?

QtQuick.Window does not have a `parent` property, only has a `transientParent` property which is of type `QWindow*` so it is not compatible with the QWidget main window.

Comment: There is [windowHandle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#windowHandle).

Comment: @iam_peter: thanks, I didn't know that. However I tried to call setParent(mainWin->windowHandle()), however that does a different thing: it embeds the QML window like a widget of the main window, and it is basically the same as calling Win32's API ::SetParent(HWND,HWND). How does Qt achieves maintaining one window always on top of another when the latter is its parent, and without using the AlwaysOnTop attribute?

Comment: How about setting the `QtQuick.Window` to `flags: Qt.Dialog`?

Comment: Nope... on Windows it goes beyond the main window. On macOS it is fine with Qt.Dialog or Qt.Tool. I solved by installing an *event-filter* in the QApplication, and adding/removing the `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` window-flag when the application gains/loses focus.

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor/tree/9f4d089f5d2868c79242c76b8f29c8834f304887) did what you are looking for. I think it may help you.